# matplotlib label cut when trying to save a subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I tried to do a basic subplot with matplotlib :

```
    plt.subplot(221)
    plt.plot(a, b)
    plt.ylabel("ylabel")


    plt.subplot(222)
    plt.plot(a, c)
    plt.ylabel('ylabel')

    plt.subplot(223)
    plt.plot(a, d)
    plt.ylabel('ylabel')


    plt.subplot(224)
    plt.plot(a, e)

    plt.ylabel('ylabel')
    plt.suptitle('Suptitle')
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.92, bottom=0.08, left=0.10, right=0.95, hspace=0.25,
                        wspace=0.45)
    plt.savefig('./images/b.png')
    plt.show()
```

But when I do my labels  are cut when I look into the png saved.

Does anyone know how to fix this ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it can be done just changing the value in the "subplot_adjusts", I was using it without knowing to what each parameters corresponded. But If I increase the parameter bottom, my xlablels are not cut anymore and if I increase the left parameter my y labels are not cut anymore.

Thank you anyway !